# partial redo/undo

Tags: undo-redo

when writing the following line a word by word:

```
word1 word2 word3
```

I want to be able to undo like this:

```
word1 word2 word
word1 word2 wor
word1 word2 w
...
```

---

If I use `u`, it will remove the entire line.

Comment: I have tried `CTRL-G u` and it doesn't work. it has same effect as `u`.  what am I doing wrong?